# HTMLCollection returns 0 as length even with document.readyState || after "DOMContentLoaded"

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, htmlcollection

I am attempting to create a list of "div" tags located inside of a parent node, which is accessed via document.querySelector('#parent-ID').

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
    let base = document.querySelector("#notion-app");
    let child = base.getElementsByTagName("div");
    console.log(child);
    console.log(child.length);
} else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        // same as above
    })
}
```

Both base and child seem to be being called correctly within the first if().
[console of child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgBdz.png)
And toward the bottom of this console output, the length is listed as 385.
[length of child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0iqf.png)

However, when I try to log child.length, it returns the number 0.
As some blogs or Q&As have suggested, I have also tried Array.prototype.slice.call(child) && for (let i=0; i<child.length; i++){}, but neither has worked for me.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

[image: screenshot of body tag in dev mode]

Comment: Could you also add the conole.logs to the code so that we know when and how you called them?

Comment: Yes, thank you for noting. Added now.

Comment: where is `document.querySelector('parent-ID')`? BTW, `'parent-ID'` should be `'#parent-ID'` if selector is supposed to reference an id. Maybe you should post HTML, but minimal ex. `<div>`...`</div><!-- 383 --><div>`...`</div>`

Comment: You are right, that was just the way I phrased my question - inaccurate I see sorry for that. The actual implementation is in line 2 as "document.querySelector("#notion-app")". The ID is located as a direct child of the body tag.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of just the body tag

Comment: Try this `const childArray = [...child]; console.log(childArray.length)`. This converts the HTML collection into an array of elements

Comment: The snippets on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState would show how you can use `document.readyState`. So, it goes *inside* an event handler.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, have tested both suggestions. The array returned an empty array []. And if my understanding is correct for the .readyState inside of the event handler (code below), then it returned the same thing as my code above, an HTMLCollection with the expected results, but a length of 0. Sorry, @tevemadar if I misunderstood, beginner

`document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {let base = document.querySelector("#notion-app");   let child = base.getElementsByTagName("div");   console.log(child);    console.log(child.length);}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE - I managed to make the code work, but still do not understand why it wasn't working.

The original structure of my code was creating a new instance of the mutation observer to listen to changes to the DOM, adding buttons to the document via insertAdjacentHTML(), and then using if(document.readyState === ...) to get the HTMLCollection and converting to an array to iterate through later on.

The solution was to simply remove either the inserAdjacentHTML command or the document.readyState condition. Then the length and any other method was successfully callable.

My problem is that regardless of whether I made these changes or not, console.log of document.readyState ALWAYS returned complete. So, according to my understanding, it shouldn't have mattered whether there was DOM manipulation or an if condition...

Anyway, that's how it worked for me and if anyone can point out what it is I am missing, I would kindly appreciate any comments.

Comment: The readystate cannot give you any relevant information about dynamically inserted elements, only those that were part of the transferred HTML document.

Comment: I see, thank you for that. When you say readyState does not give "any relevant info" I assume you mean it ignores it completely? In which case, shouldn't getElementsByTagName("div") encapsulated with if(document.readyState !== "loading") and the subsequent HTMLCollection.length still execute regardless of whether there is a dynamically inserted element or not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there‘s a couple of script tags in the body. Note that those scripts get loaded before the lower parts of the dom get rendered. If you query parts in the dom in those scripts,it won‘t find them because they didn‘t get rendered yet. Try putting the script tags at the end of the body and try it again.

Comment: thank you. The scripts displayed in the s/s above, are either CSS or config related and does not include the code I mentioned. The queries that I want to run are running after the DOM is complete. Also, I am curious, and please keep in mind I am a total noob so apol if my question doesn't make sense.
-> Should HTMLCollection see the full expected nodes on collapse (as in s/s) IF my query script was inserted before the DOM finished? (I presume NO)
-> Assuming NO, if my query script ran while some - not all - of the DOM loaded, would the partial results show up?